# Tabla con rowspan=2 en varias columnas

Tags: html

Quiero hacer una tabla con 3 columnas.
En la que algunas filas ocupen múltiples filas para las columnas primera y segunda pero no para la tercera.

Este es el código que tengo por ahora:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style=width:100%>
    <caption>Informe</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th><th>Resultado</th><th>Capturas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Test 1</th>
      <td bgcolor="#00FF00">OK</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1">Test 2</th>
      <td bgcolor="#00FF00">OK</td>
      <td><a href="file:pantalla.png">pantalla.png</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Test 3</th>
      <td bgcolor="#FF0000">FALLO</td>
      <td><a href="file:pantalla2.png">pantalla2.png</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FF0000" ></td>
      <td><a href="file:resultados.html">resultados.html</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1">Test 4</th>
      <td bgcolor="#00FF00">OK</td>
      <td><a href="file:pantalla3.png">pantalla3.png</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Que me da este resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero este resultado en que las dos filas de la columna Resultado del Test 3 están unidas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy desde el móvil y no lo he visto bien. Pero el problema que veo es que no tienes puesto el rowspan en la segunda columna.

Para la fila del Test 3 el código correcto es :

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Test 3</th>
  <td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FF0000">FALLO</td> <!-- Esta es la línea que estaba mal -->
  <td><a href="file:pantalla2.png">pantalla2.png</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <!-- Al añadir otro rowspan quitamos el td que había aquí -->
  <td><a href="file:resultados.html">resultados.html</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Pues si, eso es.